# Problems with angularJs directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I created angularjs directives:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('frontend')
    .directive('overall', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                data: '=data'
            },
            templateUrl: 'app/components/overall/overall.html',
            controller: function($scope) {
               alert($scope.data)
            }
        };
    });
```

and template for him:

```
<div id="inner-overall">
  Taras
</div>
```

After it in other page I use my directive like this:

```
<overall data></overall>
```

and js code:

```
$scope.data = 'daadad';
```

But it is not working, and I catch empty $scope.data value.
I don't know why it happens and how to fix it, help me please with this issue. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't bind model that's why it's empty

Try like this

```
<overall data="data"></overall>
```